# D3 v5: how do I animate multiple lines to be "drawn" in a multiline chart?

Tags: d3.js

Big thank you in advance, I am new to D3. I am trying to make a multiline chart that is animated, basically that acts as if the line is being "drawn" from left to right. I would like all the lines to be drawn at once.

Here is a link to the codepen project: https://codepen.io/amandaraen/project/editor/ZLLWBe

Basically, this is what I thought I should do based on Scott Murray's D3 book that I'm reading:

```
    d3.transition().selectAll(".line")
    .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 500; })
    .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
    .style("stroke", function(d, i){ 
        return colorScale(i); 
  });
```

But all this does is add the lines in their entirety one by one, instead, I would like for them to be unrolled. I have looked at lots of posts here and tried a lot of things but this is the closest I've come. Additionally, (and annoyingly) I had labels for this lines on the right hand side, but after I added the transition code the labels disappeared.

Edit, okay, I made a few changes and now, at least the labels have reappeared. So now it is only matter of how to make the lines appear like they are being drawn. Update:

```
 var country = g.selectAll(".country")
    .data(countries)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "country"); 

// draw the lines
country.append("path")
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 500; } )
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
    .style("stroke", function(d, i){ 
        return colorScale(i); 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 
Actually I would ignore my solution and try the stroke-dashed property described in this article
http://duspviz.mit.edu/d3-workshop/transitions-animation/
that I linked to through this question. 
[Animate line chart in d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467526/animate-line-chart-in-d3?rq=1)

---

To make the line appear like it is drawn, use the `attrTween` along with the built in interpolator d3.interpolateNumber to set the x2, y2 values.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no'>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh' crossorigin='anonymous'>

<title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' integrity='sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js' integrity='sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
<script src='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js' integrity='sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
<!-- d3 v5 -->
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.15.0/d3.js'></script>
<script>

let width = 500
let height = 300 
//make up some lines
let lines = [
    {
        "x1": 0, 
        "y1": 0, 
        "x2": 400, 
        "y2": 250
    },
    {
        "x1": 0, 
        "y1": 250, 
        "x2": 400, 
        "y2": 0
    }
]

//add lines 
let svg = d3.select( "body" ).style( "padding", "30px" ).append( "svg" ).attr( "height", height).attr( "width", width )


// Here you set the x1, y1, x2, y2 values of line to all be equal to x1, y1, 
// Then in your transition, use interpolate the number between x1 and x2 and y1 
// and y2 respectively. 
svg.selectAll( ".line").data( lines )
    .enter().append( "line" )
        .attr( "class", "line" )
        .attr( "stroke-width", 2 )
        .attr( "stroke", "black" )
        .attr( "x1", d => d.x1 )
        .attr( "y1", d => d.y1 )
        .attr( "x2", d => d.x1 )
        .attr( "y2", d => d.y1 )
        .transition().duration( 750 )
            .attrTween( "x2", d => {
                return d3.interpolateNumber( d.x1, d.x2 )
            })
            .attrTween( "y2", d => {
                return d3.interpolateNumber( d.y1, d.y2 )
            })



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Since this is a line it was easy to use the build in interpolator, but if it was a path or something you can define your own. I found this to be a great reference. 
https://www.andyshora.com/tweening-shapes-paths-d3-js.html

EDIT: I realized you were making paths. I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but you can break the path up at each node to create list of segments. For example, if the path was ABCD you would get 
A
AB
ABC 
ABCD

Then you can each line with a delay so A is drawn, then AB, then ABC, etc.

```
let width = 500
let height = 300 

//get some paths 
let paths = [
    getPath( .5, 0 ), 
    getPath( .25, 0 )
]

// for each path, take a length from 0-i 
// So for path [(0,0), (1, 1), (2,2)] => 
// [ [(0,0)], [(0,0),(1,1)], [(0,0), (1,1), (2,2)] ]
let pathSegments = paths.map( p => segmentPath( p ))


//make the line generator
var lineGenerator = d3.line()
.x(function(d, i) {
    return d.x;
})
.y(function(d) {
    return d.y;
});

//add the svg
let svg = d3.select("body").style("padding", "30px").append( "svg" ).attr( "height", height).attr( "width", width)


//add the group elements which will contain the segments for each line - merge with update selection - 
let lines = svg.selectAll( ".line" ).data( pathSegments )
lines = lines.enter().append( "g" )
    .attr( "class", "line" )
    .merge( lines )

//To add line to g,  selectAll to add the segments - data bound to lines will be passed 
// down to children if data is called - in this case .data( d => d ) - d is the segmented 
// path [ [(0,0)], [(0,0),(1,1)], [(0,0), (1,1), (2,2)] ] for a single line
// add a delay on stroke-width to give the appearance of being drawn
lines.selectAll( ".segment" ).data( d => d )
    .enter().append( "path" )
        .attr( "class", "segment" )
        .attr( "stroke", "black" )
        .attr( "stroke-width", 0 )
        .attr( "fill", "none" )
        .attr( "d", lineGenerator )
        .transition().duration(750)
        .delay( (d,i) => i * 100 )
            .attr( "stroke-width", 2 )


//helper functions
function getPath( m, b ) {
    let line = [...Array(5).keys()].map( d => {
        return {
            "x": d * 100, 
            "y": m * d * 100 + b,
        }
    })
    return line
}
function segmentPath( path ) {
    let segments = []
    for( let i=1; i < path.length; i++ ) {
        segments.push( path.slice(0, i ))
    }
    return segments 

}
```

Of course, you might want to remove the extra segments after adding. Also, it only works if the path segments are small enough to make a smooth transition. If not, segment the line further, or break the path into a set of lines and use the x1,y1,x2,y2 interpolation from above.

Comment: This code is way beyond my level and very difficult for me to understand, but I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Ok, well hope you figured it out. If not check out this article, I think you can do it with a couple lines of css. Best. https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/